# Can I instrument Java code remotely using JMX?

Tags: java

I would like to be able to instrument Java code without adding any agents or jars to the application I am monitoring (Weblogic in my case). Is this possible?

Comment: Can you instrument the jars before they are loaded?

Comment: No I can't access the jars before they are loaded, as I do not as the application is already running when I connect to it

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom MBeans that expose fields in your application and monitor these using a tool like [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), but this is pretty inflexible when used as a method of profiling.  It means whatever instrumentation you have is built into your application.  The advantage of using agents is they add instrumentation to your classes on the fly, and it can easily be added or removed dynamically.

Comment: Can I instrument things like how long methods take to execute like this?

Comment: Have you considered using something like VisualVM?  Why would you want to write this code yourself?  You can do it easily - on method entry call currentTimeMillis(), on exit, do it again and take the difference.

Comment: I didn't know that VisualVM could do this, thanks Amir. Does VisualVM use JMX to do this then?

Comment: I tried JVisualVM but I can't get it to connect to my remote weblogic server. Connecting using JMX and T3 works fine though

Comment: Are you running a newer JDK?  Is your remote box behind a firewall?  You should be able to find instructions on google for how to connect to it.

Comment: using JRockit R28 with JDK 1.5 on the remote box. And I access the box via an SSH tunnel (as it is behind a firewall)